# Changing JSON to Dataframe in python

Tags: python

I want to change the API json response to dataframe by making columns under data to dataframe. Note it also has some nested parameters under data (message) I want to make it individual columns.

```py
{
    'success': True,
    'code': 200,
    'data': [
        {
            'id': 342964769,
            'type': 'ios',
            'create_time': 1567591650,
            'open_count': 2,
            'environment': 'production',
            'campaign_id': 12713145,
            'project_id': 1758,
            'error': 0,
            'sent_count': 3,
            'message': {
                'timestamp': '1567591643',
                'badge': '',
                'alert': "'I pulled pints and cut turf here back in the day' - Mike Pence speaks to "
                                 "small crowd in Doonbeg",
                'sound': 'default',
                'articleId': '38465289',
                'category': 'news/',
                'id': '342964769',
                'pushId': 'fireabse-5d6f8cdb8c3e9',
                'title': 'Independent.ie',
                'content-available': '1',
                'xpush': 'yes',
                'cid': '12713145'
            },
            'error_message': None
        }, {
            'id': 342964771,
            'type': 'android',
            'create_time': 1567591650,
            'open_count': 0,
            'environment': 'production',
            'campaign_id': 12713145,
            'project_id': 1758,
            'error': 0,
            'sent_count': 0,
            'message': None,
            'error_message': None
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(resp['data'])`` ??

Comment: @sushanth that works but the thing is if I want to to segregate the message columns as well then which is nested then how should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what you want?

```
def dict_pop(d, *args):
    v = d.pop(*args)
    return v if v else {}

resp = [{**dict_pop(i,'message'), **i} for i in resp['data']]
resp = pd.DataFrame(resp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the dictionaries by removing the `message` level and making each entry of the dictionary part of the parent dict:

```py
import pandas as pd
import copy

data = {
    'success': True,
    'code': 200,
    'data': [
        {
            'id': 342964769,
            'type': 'ios',
            'create_time': 1567591650,
            'open_count': 2,
            'environment': 'production',
            'campaign_id': 12713145,
            'project_id': 1758,
            'error': 0,
            'sent_count': 3,
            'message': {
                'timestamp': '1567591643',
                'badge': '',
                'alert': "'I pulled pints and cut turf here back in the day' - Mike Pence speaks to "
                                 "small crowd in Doonbeg",
                'sound': 'default',
                'articleId': '38465289',
                'category': 'news/',
                'id': '342964769',
                'pushId': 'fireabse-5d6f8cdb8c3e9',
                'title': 'Independent.ie',
                'content-available': '1',
                'xpush': 'yes',
                'cid': '12713145'
            },
            'error_message': None
        }, {
            'id': 342964771,
            'type': 'android',
            'create_time': 1567591650,
            'open_count': 0,
            'environment': 'production',
            'campaign_id': 12713145,
            'project_id': 1758,
            'error': 0,
            'sent_count': 0,
            'message': None,
            'error_message': None
        }
    ]
}

processed = []
for dat in data["data"]:
    new_dat = copy.deepcopy(dat)  # only important if the original data matters to you
    if "message" in new_dat and new_dat["message"]:
        message = new_dat.pop("message")
        new_dat.update(message)
    processed.append(new_dat)

df = pd.DataFrame(processed)
print(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['id', 'type', 'create_time', 'open_count', 'environment', 'campaign_id',
       'project_id', 'error', 'sent_count', 'error_message', 'timestamp',
       'badge', 'alert', 'sound', 'articleId', 'category', 'pushId', 'title',
       'content-available', 'xpush', 'cid', 'message'],
      dtype='object')
```